# Following a segue to a view controller from appdelegate

Tags: ios, swift2, segue, uistoryboard

What is the correct way to segue to a view controller from the app delegate? When I get a push notification, I am transitioning the user to a view controller, however, the views are not complete. The navigation bar does not look right. Here's my setup:

```
tabviewcontroller (storyboard name is 'main')
 - nav1controller -> view1controller -? view1detailcontroller (storyboard name is 'view1detail')
 - nav2controller -> ...
```

When a push notification arrives, I want to take the user to veiw1detailcontroller. I want to allow the user to go back to view1controller.

This is the code I have:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let mainViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("main") as! UIViewController

let view1detailcontroller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view1detail") as! view1detailcontroller

let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController)
nav.pushViewController(view1detailcontroller, animated: true)
self.window!.rootViewController = nav
```

So, it transitions fine to view1detailcontroller. However, once I go back to view1controller, the navigation bar on that screen and on all other screens say "main", and all the navigation items are missing as well.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what the use of this one `nav.pushViewController(view1detailcontroller, animated: true)`

Comment: I need to transition to view1detailcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating a new navigation controller, and setting `self.window!.rootViewController = nav`, you are basically resetting the entire view stack. (e.g. you will loose the `tabviewcontroller` mentioned in your first view hierarchy quote)

Instead, access the existing tab view controller and it's child navigation controller to push your new view controller. If you need more help with how this can be done, you need to share more code / storyboard screen shot to understand your existing set up.

**EDIT**

From your comments, it seems (although not very clear), that your `self.wondow.rootViewController` is already your 'tabBarController' which contains navigation controllers. Assuming this, and that you know the index of your intended navigation controller within the tabbarcontroller, you can do the following to open your intended view controller with hierarchy

1. On receiving the push notification access the tabBaController :

   if let tabBarController = self.window.rootViewController as? UITabBarController
2. Access the navigation controller within the tab bar controller :  (code assumes intended nav controller is the first tab. Change index in code according to your setup)

   if let navController = tabBarController.viewControllers[0] as? UITabBarController
3. Create an array of all the view controllers you want on this nav controller and set them using `setViewControllers` method :

   var viewControllersArray : [UIViewController] = UIViewController;
   viewControllersArray.append(view1controller)
   viewControllersArray.append(view1detailcontroller)
   navController.setViewControllers(viewControllers : viewControllersArray, animated : true)
4. Here, instantiate `view1controller` and `view1detailcontroller` as you do in your code form storyboard and note the following form [setViewControllers documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621861-setviewcontrollers)

> the last item added to the array becomes the top item of the
>   navigation stack

Comment: Thanks. How do I access the navigation controller of the tabview controller? I have my tabview controller like this: var mainViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("main") as UIViewController
self.window?.rootViewController = mainViewController

Comment: Wait! In the question, your code mentions `main` as storyboard identifier of you view controller which you are trying to push and in this comment you say its the identifier of your tabviewcontroller. Which one is it?

Comment: the name of the tab viewcontoller in my storyboard is 'main'.  It has a navigation controller, which has two view controllers (view1controller and view1detailcontroller). Basically, I want the user to go to view1detailcontroller, while maintaining the back button and tabs.

Answer (score 0):

instead of pushing view controller direct from main storyboard, you should get topViewController or visibleController and push desired viewController on topController, so that it will maintain your stacks of ViewController and you will get what you want.

Comment: Could you please help me out with some code? I'm new to swift. Thanks!

Comment: i can write a algo like how you should do

Comment: i can write a algo like how you should do , like first get window rootviewcontroller it must be your navigationController and then get topController on UINavigationController if that is detailViewController then use this and push your data, otherwise traverse all controllers of UINavigationController's stack controller and get the object of detailController and use this VC to push your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
    var rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as UINavigationController
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view") as ViewController
    rootViewController.pushToViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: The problem with this is it does not retain my tab views and navigation stack.

Comment: You can set in the next view controller:  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}